# Visual svn adding overlay icons to strange directories

Tags: icons, overlay, visualsvn

I'm using Visual SVN on my windows machine and so far everything has been working fine. But since a couple of days, I've got overlay icons (the questionmark) over c:\Programme c:\Recycler and a couple of other folders on my c:\ drive. All programming related stuff is on d:\, so I find it weird and it's pretty much irritating me to see them.

I've been searching for .svn files and directories hoping that if I'd remove them, the overlays will disappear, but I didn't finde any files or directories.

Does anyone know this problem? Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since VisualSVN uses TortoiseSVN under the hood, my guess is these are coming from Tortoise.  I've had issues with the Tortoise cache process slowing my machine or sometimes not updating immediately in Windows explorer.  You might look at [this article](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2007/09/26/optimize-tortoise-svn-cache-tsvncache.exe-disk-io.aspx) which describes how to set the caching settings to only look in directories where you keep working copies.

Comment: I just want to add, the exact instructions on that page are outdated. For current version, to get the same page you want to look in "Icon Overlays" in the settings.